# API for 3D modeling in c#

Tags: c#, 3d-modelling

I want to know what API can i used to create an 3D from sequence of images. my project is to calculate liver volume through CT images. At the moment i'm searching for an  API which can generate the liver model via sequence of extracted liver regions. could u please suggest  API asap? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

A common option for this is [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/).  Kitware has a [C# API for VTK called ActiViz](http://www.kitware.com/products/activiz.html).

It allows you to build the model from the images, as well as do volume or geometrical rendering of the features, subsetting, volume calculation, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply!! it will be much better if that allows to do volume calculation via the model. :)

Comment: @jackfernandz It does.  It's geared towards scientific and medical visualization, so it's for exactly what you're attempting...

Comment: yes that's what i wanted! i was planning to do a virtual surgery system! when user imports the CT image seiris, the system will extract the liver from other organs and the liver model would be created. Then user will be able to resect the portion that should be removed and the volumes of the separated parts should be calculated. That's what i was planning. The crucial part is to extract the liver from the other organs. At the moment i'm doing that!

Answer (score 0):

XNA game studio might be a good for you, its a game platform but you could create a very nice looking stand alone application with it, or you could host the XNA part within an existing Forms Application:

Its c#

Its Free and fully supported by microsoft

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23714

Its relatively easy to get started

It 3d Hardware accelerated

It supports a number of platforms (PC, Phone and Xbox)

You can integrated/host the 'game' inside an existing forms application

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1

There are lots of tutorials and samples available:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203897(v=xnagamestudio.31).aspx

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/?contenttype=0&devarea=6&platform=0&sort=1

Comment: Many thanks for the reply!! :) i just looked at XNA game studio!

Comment: Thanks!! i think VTK will be most suited since its has volume rending. As i mentioned in the previous comment the system should be able to calculated the volumes of the separated parts by the user. Sorry i couldn't mentioned my whole project scenario.